# Why won't this PHP script insert form data in MySQL db?

Tags: php, mysql

On form submit, I'm getting a blank page (insert.php) with no error and no success message.

This is the form:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Firstname: <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" />
Lastname: <input type="text" name="lastname" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This is the script:

```
mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);


$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (first_name) VALUES (:first_name)');

$stmt->execute(':first_name', $first_name);


if (!mysql_query($stmt,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: is that actually all of the code?  where are you getting $first_name from?

Comment: parse error? have you checked the logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a PDO object to be able to use prepared statements. Instead you have opened a connection with `mysql_connect()`. The two do not mix, and PDO is preferred between them as it is more easily secured through the use of prepared statements (among other reasons).

From [the PDO docs:](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

```
// This establishes your connection using PDO.
// The PDO connection object is $db

/* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Pass an associative array to `execute()`, rather than a list of arguments representing your placeholders.  The

```
// Now that the PDO object is successfully created, prepare your statement
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (first_name) VALUES (:first_name)');

// Arg to execute() should be an associative array
$stmt->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name));
```

The following call to `mysql_query()` is unnecessary, as you have already executed the prepared statement with PDO.

```
// Don't do this
// mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

// Or this...
//if (!mysql_query($stmt,$con))
//{
//  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
//}

// Or this...
// mysql_close($con)
```

Answer (score 3):

Youre trying to use 2 different MySQL interfaces at the same time. The `mysql_*` family of functions use the [`ext/mysql`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) extension... The [prepared statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) stuff is [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). You need to choose one or the other. Since PDO is really the way to go ill give you an example with that:

```
$db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

try {
   $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO my_table (first_name) VALUES (:first_name)');
   if($stmt->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name))) {
      echo "1 record added";
   }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());

}
```

The docs on the Mysql DSN (the first argument to the [PDO constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)) can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Comment: Thanks. I'm on my way again. I guess this wasn't mentioned (or it was assumed I'd know) in [my post yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624292/is-this-a-secure-method-to-insert-form-data-into-a-mysql-database).

Comment: Yeah it was probably assumed youd not just copy and paste, but rather go and investigate the Docs for PDO and then realize its a completely different extension with a different interface from the examples found there.