# SQL Injection Attack through form input

Tags: php, mysql, sql, code-injection

Hi I want to show sql injection vulnerability through form input using PHP and MYSQL. Any suggestion how to go about.

Thanks

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but it sounds like this fits:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9624292/is-this-a-secure-method-to-insert-form-data-into-a-mysql-database?lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: in your input that connects to a mysql function, try use sql functions like DELETE table_name; or TRUNCATE table_name

Comment: You might also want to tag it with mysql and php rather than sql so the right people come here. The SQL tag is a bit too ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks for replying excuse me for being vague. I know how to prevent sql injection by adding striplashes and real_escape_string. I want to demonstrate a vulnerable login which is not working by simply removing the striplashes. I even tried; admin' 1-- and its giving me wrong username or password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES ('$inject_variable')");
```

If you have query like this you can insert something like `value'); DROP TABLE table;--` to the `$inject_variable` to test the injection.

Hence, your SQL query will became this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES('value'); DROP TABLE table;--')
```

This will allow other users to drop the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kali Linux to hack into the php website. Here is a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/NpucWg7fz7k) on how to do that.